# ASP.NET: Read cookies from another application

Tags: asp.net, cookies

We have several web applications. When we run anyone of them we enter username and password and some cookies (user id) have been sent to client computer. When we run some another application, we should be able to check if we already logged on in some of our applications and if so, we automatically logged on to other applications without entering username and password.

It seems we should search for cookies in other applications to check if they exist. As I know cookies exist in context of particular web application and I'm not sure if we can check their existence in other applications.

How to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ASP.NET Single Sign-On Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation)

Comment: You can't read cookies form other sites. You seem to be looking for Single Sign On.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web applications are being hosted in sub-domains of the same domain (e.g. `exchange.contoso.com` and `mail.contoso.com`), then you can easily exchange cookies between sub-domains by setting the "Domain" property of the [HttpCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object to `.contoso.com`:

```
Response.Cookies["auth"].Domain = ".contoso.com";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @tesicg This cookie will be available with the given HTTP request, just like any other: `var val = Request.Cookies["auth"].Value`.

Comment: I've used the following code to add cookie with domain:

HttpCookie accessTokenCookie = new HttpCookie("access_token", token.TokenId);
accessTokenCookie.Domain = ".Concert.ru";
responseCookies.Add(accessTokenCookie);

But, it's not displayed in the list of cookies. What's wrong?

Comment: Should domain name be real? I mean not like, for example: hello.

Comment: @tesicg It should be, with the next request. Try setting the "Expires" property to a month in the future. And yes, the domain name must be the one you're using to request the website (`.concert.ru`, I guess).

Comment: And one more question - how to delete cookie with domain scope? I delete them in this way:

var accessTokenCookie = new HttpCookie("access_token");
accessTokenCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
response.Cookies.Add(accessTokenCookie);

Comment: @tesicg That's I believe one of the "proper" ways to do it since you still need to notify the browser that the cookie is no longer valid and that it should delete it. Setting the validity date in the past and sending the cookie over to the client does the trick.