# Single Sign On with AspNetZero

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I am working on ASP.NET ZERO with core 2.0 and jQuery. ASP.NET ZERO has 2 web projects Web.Mvc(main web app) & Web.Public. In web.Public project to do login it redirects to Web.Mvc with query string which mentions sso true in query string , after login it redirects back to public project.

Case1: When we click on Login from Public project, it will redirect to Web project. Once we successfully logged-in by entering user credentials,it will redirect to Public project and in that, we are not getting user from session(AbpSesion.UserId). If we refresh main Web project then it is logged in and user name will be displayed in header. But this is not working on Public project and it is still displaying Login link instead of logged in user name in header.
If we click Login link again then it goes to main web app and get redirect back again to home page of public , so it seems we are already login in main web app properly.

Case2: After above process, if we logout from Web project and then refresh Public project, user name will be there in header and we are getting both user and tenant session values and it works well.

==>Summary: Once User logged in successfully from Public to Web, Web project is sending user information to Public and Public project is also retrieving that information but in between there is one Application Service layer in which we are not getting userid from AbpSession values(AbpSesion.UserId) due to which Single-Sign-On functionality seems to be not working.

Note able to find any more info on such issue for ASP.NET ZERO in any threads or documents.

Thanks

Comment: https://support.aspnetzero.com/

Comment: [off-topic]  this forum is for asp.net boilerplate (abp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in local:
[Asp.net Identity SSO in multiple projects on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000097/asp-net-identity-sso-in-multiple-projects-on-localhost)

It will help to share identity between multiple applications.