# JOSSO - What is the basic setup step

Tags: josso

I'm on a task that implement SSO using josso, but i am very new to this aspect. I have an website on asp.net MVC4 using IIS. I have tried to install JOSSO 2.0 on my machine but i do not know where to start. Can you give me details of it
Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation

Comment: In this case i'm using JOSSO. and i dont know where to start