# How to configure single sign on for a C#.net web application?

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, adfs

I have an application developed in C# .net. My department wants me to configure single sign on for the same application. my application is HTTP secure(hTTPS).How to configure SSO? I have a little idea about creating some XML file through IIS but how to create that file ? (let me know if i need to post any screenshots)

Can anyone explain the process for the same? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation

Comment: For SSO, you normally use a product like ADFS or Azure AD. Is this along the lines you were thinking?

Comment: yes nzpcmad. ADFS will be used but how to achieve it using IIS and the .NET application?