# Single Sign On in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I need to implement Single Sign On using Windows Authentication in a MVC application for Intranet users.

Can someone please explain it to me how to proceed, or refer me to some articles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# ASP.NET Single Sign-On Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation)

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions like this on StackOverflow.