# MVC5 using MFA (Microsoft Authenticator App)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

I am looking after a legacy app using MVC 5. Is it possible to integrate MFA (Microsoft Authenticator App) to this web application?

All articles from Microsoft seem to use the new .net core

Thank you

Comment: There are two parts to this. First, you need to integrate Single Sign On into your project. Then you'll have to set up the authentication flow in Actice Directory or Azure. You technically don't integrate the MS app itself into your project, but rather Active Directory. And then you tell active directory to use MFA.

Comment: Have a loot at the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation

Comment: @captain kenpachi, my web application is not using AD, but the built-in ASP.Net Identity Membership, so the login details are stored in db table

Comment: Then you won't be able to use the MS authenticator app, but you can still write a custom SMS/Email code authentication method. It's not hard. You generate a token, save it to the DB, then send it to a user's phone or email, then he fills it in and you verify it against what you saved in the DB.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Thanks that's what I'm afraid of. I found this article  https://sabbour.me/securing-asp-net-logins-with-azure-multi-factor-authentication/ - it seems what I was trying to achieve used to be possible, but not after Microsoft made a change in 2018 to disable the MFA server and force people to use Azure AD. Is that correct?

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Sorry for commenting to an old question, but I doubt the info you gave in the previous comments are accurate. I'm using the MS Authenticator app for sites like NPM, Twitter and Plex for example. I doubt that they implemented Single Sign On with AD.