# How to make auto Login to Website 'B' when user already login to Website 'A'

Tags: c#, .net-core, reactjs.net

I've 2 web site A & B and their databases are different. When any user is logged in on website A and later on same user is going to open website B then user should automatically logged on website B.

Please suggest how I can implement this.

My both application has been developed using *.net core with react*

Comment: Depends how you want to do it, and how your current login works. If the apps are on the same domain, then you can reuse cookies tokens etc. You could implement an `OAuth` client / server. Pass a JWT via a jsonp request. Or literally anything else...

Comment: For React I think JWT SSO is batter idea to achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

Strongly depends on how/where your site is hosted.
if its hosted via IIS as an intranet application you could use windows authentication.
Another idea would include a Single Sign-On implementation.
Read into this thread for further details:
[C# ASP.NET Single Sign-On Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation)

Comment: Thanks for sharing such details. In my case no link to redirect user from site 'A' to site 'B'. User only can open site 'B' by directly typing URL in browser.

Also, yes both site hosted on IIS